# Random number generator in php with twist

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am working on a php Projekt for school.
It includes customers and employees. I want to assign a employee to a customer which created a account automatically, but it shouldn't be allowed to only have 1 employee for all customers.
It should be even separated. So for example there are 2 employees and 10 customers each then should have 5 customers and not 3 / 7 etc. .

I somehow know how to randomize but the distribution is the problem.
Code looks like this for now:

```
<?php
    //1. Verbindungsaufbau
    $nm = $_POST['nm'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $vname = $_POST['vname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gold-market_main', 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
    
    $query = $pdo->query('SELECT MAX(kundenNr) AS sum FROM kunden');

    $r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sum = $r['sum'];

    $kundenMAX = $sum + 1;
 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO kunden VALUES ('$kundenMAX', '$nm', '$pw','$name','$vname','$email',$emp)";
    $count = $pdo->exec($sql);

  
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "<div>Der Datensatz wurde erfolgreich gespeichert</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div>Der Datensatz konnte nicht gespeichert werden</div>";
    }

    //4. Verbindungsabbau
    $pdo = null;
?>
```

Table:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Erstellungszeit: 28. Mai 2022 um 19:05
-- Server-Version: 10.5.12-MariaDB-0+deb11u1
-- PHP-Version: 7.1.33

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Datenbank: `gold-market_main`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `mitarbeiter`
--

CREATE TABLE `mitarbeiter` (
  `mitarbeiterNr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `m_name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_vorname` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_benutzername` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_passwort` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `mitarbeiter`
--

INSERT INTO `mitarbeiter` (`mitarbeiterNr`, `m_name`, `m_vorname`, `m_benutzername`, `m_passwort`) VALUES
(1, 'Dickins', 'Chad', 'dickie123', '1234');

--
-- Indizes der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `mitarbeiter`
--
ALTER TABLE `mitarbeiter`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`mitarbeiterNr`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Second Table:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Erstellungszeit: 28. Mai 2022 um 19:05
-- Server-Version: 10.5.12-MariaDB-0+deb11u1
-- PHP-Version: 7.1.33

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Datenbank: `gold-market_main`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `kunden`
--

CREATE TABLE `kunden` (
  `kundenNr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `k_nutzername` varchar(45) DEFAULT '''NULL''',
  `k_passwort` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'NULL',
  `k_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `k_nachname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `k_email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mitarbeiterNr` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `kunden`
--

INSERT INTO `kunden` (`kundenNr`, `k_nutzername`, `k_passwort`, `k_name`, `k_nachname`, `k_email`, `mitarbeiterNr`) VALUES
(1, 'aToMike', '1234', 'Mike', 'Thomson', 'thomson@mike.com', 1),
(2, 'gabriel.test', 'test12', 'Gabriel', 'Test', 'gabriel@test.de', 1);

--
-- Indizes der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `kunden`
--
ALTER TABLE `kunden`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`kundenNr`),
  ADD KEY `fk_persoenlicheDaten_mitarbeiter1_idx` (`mitarbeiterNr`);

--
-- Constraints der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Constraints der Tabelle `kunden`
--
ALTER TABLE `kunden`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_persoenlicheDaten_mitarbeiter1` FOREIGN KEY (`mitarbeiterNr`) REFERENCES `mitarbeiter` (`mitarbeiterNr`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: What if no. of employees doesn't evenly divide no. of customers? Who will be that extra time worker guy?

Comment: then just random assign one so if its 7 customers randomly pick employee 1 or 2

Comment: You mean assign that to any random employee?

Comment: yes, I just want it to be somehow evenly separated.

Comment: @siie1wnl Can you add the structure of your two db tables?

Comment: I added them I hope this helps I am still pretty new to coding. If this is not what you ment let me know

Comment: @siie1wnl Yeah, that's perfect, maybe try to get used to naming things in English. I'm from Switzerland and did the same thing when I started coding. But its sooo much nicer to read and for other peoplo around the world easyer to understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this sql command you can get the employe ID, which has the lowest amount of customers assigned

`SELECT mitarbeiterNr, count(*) AS mitarbeiterCount FROM kunden GROUP BY mitarbeiterNr ORDER BY mitarbeiterCount ASC LIMIT 1`

[image: Query Result]

[image: Kunden table]

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$emp= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$emp[0]; // Outputs 2
```

Comment: Thank you really much. So in theory i can do SELECT mitarbeiterNr AS $emp and then add this to my second Command INSERT INTO and then just use $emp. right?

Comment: I would create a new query with the whole sql command I posted and save the result in a variable like $emp.

Comment: It defenetly helps I just need to figure out how to use it in the INSERT INTO command. I just need to figure out how to accept your answer haha.

Comment: Got it I believe, let me know if this is not what you ment.

Comment: Why do you want to use it in the INSERT INTO command?

Comment: In your example mitarbeiterNr 2 has the least customers (mitarbeiterCount = 1).
Therefore I want to assign mitarbeiterNr 2 to the next customer. Since I want the distribution to be even of the customers to the employees if this makes sense.
(As I tried to explain in the scenario before:
If I have 10 customers and 2 employees both employees should have 5 customers)
So If a new customer registers to my webside he will be assigned a employee automatically. Therefore I need the INSERT INTO command

Comment: Exactly yes. So in this case you want to set the MitarbeiterNr to 2 for the new customer that would get created

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: ```
$sql2= 'SELECT mitarbeiterNr, count(*) AS mitarbeiterCount FROM kunden GROUP BY mitarbeiterNr ORDER BY mitarbeiterCount ASC LIMIT 1';
    $result = $pdo->query($sql2);

    $emp = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO kunden VALUES ('$kundenMAX', '$nm', '$pw','$name','$vname','$email',$emp)";
```
Code looks like this right now but it doesn't work haha.

Comment: Yes but you already have a INSERT INTO statement, just use this one and set the $emp to the mitarbeiterNr you got from the query

Comment: So I type $emp = mitarbeiterNr ?

Comment: @siie1wnl I edited my answer on how to get the mitarbeiterNr into a variable, hope it helps

Comment: @siie1wnl your code is neraly correct. Currently your $emp is an array beacuase of $emp = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); Thats good but you need to get the first element out of the array -> $emp[0] should give you "2".

Comment: It all makes sense but it still protests: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gold-market_main`.`kunden`, CONSTRAINT `fk_persoenlicheDaten_mitarbeiter1` FOREIGN KEY (`mitarbeiterNr`) REFERENCES `mitarbeiter` (`mitarbeiterNr`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) in /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php:27 Stack trace: #0 /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php(27): PDO->exec('INSERT INTO kun...') #1 {main} thrown in /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php on

Comment: Now i fixed it till this happens: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 arguments, 1 given in /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php(23): mysqli_query('SELECT mitarbei...') #1 {main} thrown in /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php on line 23

Comment: Did u use the code you wrote before

Comment: Try this:
`   $sql2= 'SELECT mitarbeiterNr, count(*) AS mitarbeiterCount FROM kunden GROUP BY mitarbeiterNr ORDER BY mitarbeiterCount ASC LIMIT 1';
    $result = $pdo->query($sql2);
    $emp = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO kunden VALUES ('$kundenMAX', '$nm', '$pw','$name','$vname','$email', '$emp[0]')";`

Comment: then same error pops up: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 arguments, 1 given in /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php(23): mysqli_query('SELECT mitarbei...') #1 {main} thrown in /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php on line 23

Comment: Where have you used mysqli_query?

Comment: I didn't (atleast I can't find it). Could it be because of `$count = $pdo->exec($sql);
`?

Comment: nope that shouldn't be the error exec only needs one parameter

Comment: The error message says that the error is in the file: new_acc.php On the line: 23

Comment: the $count was above my $sql that was the problem but new errors just accured.Warning: Undefined array key 0 in /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php on line 27

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gold-market_main`.`kunden`, CONSTRAINT `fk_persoenlicheDaten_mitarbeiter1` FOREIGN KEY (`mitarbeiterNr`) REFERENCES `mitarbeiter` (`mitarbeiterNr`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) in /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php:28 Stack trace: #0 /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php(28): PDO->exec('INSERT INTO kun...') #1 {main} thrown in /users/gold-market/www/new_acc/new_acc.php on line 28

Comment: What is on line 28

Comment: $count = $pdo->exec($sql);

Comment: Ok that means that there is an error in your $sql

Comment: I am talking with a mate he said that we are mixing things up since you use mysqli and we use PDO

Comment: but he doesn't know what to do too

Comment: yeah thats true but the query SELECT mitarbeiterNr, count(*) AS mitarbeiterCount FROM kunden GROUP BY mitarbeiterNr ORDER BY mitarbeiterCount ASC LIMIT 1 works with PDO and mysqli

Comment: Could you send me the line where you declare your $sql variable

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO kunden VALUES ('$kundenMAX', '$nm', '$pw','$name','$vname','$email', '$emp[0]')";

Comment: ok the query looks correct. Do you still get the error that $emp has an undefined array key? If yes try to do var_dump($emp) to see whats in the variable.

Comment: nothing happens just same error

Comment: Her is a link on how to debug a php script maybe it helps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-debug-php-scripts/

Comment: But the process is clear to you. get the query results from the sql -> convert them to an arry -> get the first result to get the mitarbeiterNR -> insert them into kunden

Comment: So I got it now: fetch->(PDO :: ASSOC) or whatever it was, was the problem it has to be 
fetch->() and then it works.
Thank you again for your time and help.

Comment: Ahh perfect, your welcome